# QGIS Build error : zzz-db_manager-5-depend error - qgis master 2.99

Tags: pyqgis, pyqt, python-3

I am compiling  QGIS from master in VS 2015 on x64.

I am getting error as :

Error MSB6006 "cmd.exe" exited with code 1. zzz-db_manager-5-depend 7 C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets

and output followed by :

Build started: Project: version, Configuration: RelWithDebInfo x64
Build started: Project: ui, Configuration: RelWithDebInfo x64
Build started: Project: zzz-db_manager-5-depend, Configuration: RelWithDebInfo x64
Building Custom Rule C:/QGIS/python/plugins/db_manager/db_plugins/postgis/plugins/versioning/CMakeLists.txt
CMake does not need to re-run because C:\build3\python\plugins\db_manager\db_plugins\postgis\plugins\versioning\CMakeFiles\generate.stamp is up-to-date.
Generating ui_DlgVersioning.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\QGIS\scripts\pyuic-wrapper.py", line 26, in  import qgis.PyQt.uic.pyuic
File "C:\build3\output\python\qgis__init__.py", line 71, in  from qgis.PyQt import QtCore
File "C:\build3\output\python\qgis\PyQt\QtCore.py", line 1, in  from PyQt5.QtCore import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(171,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 1.
========== Build: 2 succeeded, 1 failed, 10 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
Can any one help me to get out of this?